# ASP.NET deploy on Google Cloud Platform - Windows 10x64

Tags: c#, asp.net, sdk, cloud

Is anybody has a link to tutorial how to deploy ASP.NET app on Google Cloud Platform on Win 10x64. I spent couple of days to maintain the environment. By the way, I dailed to do it - lots of error with encoding problems, connection problems and etc. Who did the reployment on windows, or has a source to share, leave the comments, please.

Answer (score 0):

Presently, it is not possible to deploy a Windows *10* image to Google Compute Engine.  You can deploy Windows Server, versions 2008, 2012, or 2016.  See:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/#windows_server